# Reminders added as Chrome link instead of Safari

Tags: safari, google-chrome, reminders

As said in the subject, every time I add a to-do in Reminders.app from the Safari 'share' button, it gets created as Chrome Link, rather than Safari. Therefore when I click on it, it opens Chrome.

[image]

I have checked and Safari is correctly set as default browser in preferences, and in the Reminders.app preferences there's nothing related to browser.

For Reminders.app I mean the native macOS application.

**UPDATE**

If I do the same action on iOS, the link is correctly added as a Safari link, and trough the iCloud I get the to-do as Safari link as well. So it is something that macOS is doing.

Also, I have exported the to-do list and opened with text edit:

This is the to-do from iOS, which works fine:

```
BEGIN:VTODO
STATUS:NEEDS-ACTION
CREATED:20180211T174107Z
UID:E24E9CDA-5989-481F-B83C-4165E77430A2
X-APPLE-SORT-ORDER:540063667
SUMMARY:ESPN: The Worldwide Leader in Sports
X-APPLE-ACTIVITY;VALUE=URI:http://www.espn.com/
DTSTAMP:20180211T174108Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20180211T174107Z
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:⁦‪espn.com‬⁩
END:VTODO
```

This is instead the to-do added from macOS, as you can see there is a whole new section `X-APPLE-APP-LINK-DATA` filled with Base64 data:

```
BEGIN:VTODO
CREATED:20180211T075213Z
UID:A3F55E30-B56B-4E37-8495-C81B5805B771
X-APPLE-APP-LINK-DATA:YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUG...lot more chars removed for clarity
SUMMARY:Reminders added as Chrome link instead of Safari - Ask Different
DTSTAMP:20180211T075222Z
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:⁦‪apple.stackexchange.com‬⁩
END:VTODO
```

Comment: if you paste a link, say in textEdit or any other native app and click on it does it also go to chrome? or is it specific to Reminders?

Comment: Created a link in TextEdit and clicked on it. It opens Safari, so it seems specific to Reminders